# Why is my .bashrc and .bash_profile different from echo $path

Tags: bash, laravel-valet

i was trying to add something to my path. But since i'm nog very familiar with the terminal i think i messed something up.

when i do `echo $PATH` i get:

```
/Users/christoph/.node/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

but when i open `.bashrc` i see this:

```
alias homestead=~/.composer/vendor/bin/homestead

echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

And when i open .bash_profile i see this:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.node/bin:$PATH"
```

I want to do this step : (to install laravel valet)

> Install Valet with Composer via composer global require laravel/valet.
>   Make sure the ~/.composer/vendor/bin directory is in your system's
>   "PATH".

And i am very confused on how i should add this path. Also in which file do i need to put it?

I am using MAC OSX El Capitan

Comment: see if this helps: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove this line from your `.bashrc`!!!

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

It appends a new line to your bashrc each time you log in.

Overall you should modify your PATH env variable only in single file (`.bash_profile`, but many people will make an error of modifying `.bashrc`). It works like this: PATH is list of directories splitted by ':' character, `$PATH` expands to previous value of this list. Example:

```
export PATH=/fooo:/barr:/bazzz
```

Places exactly these tree directories in PATH variable. In your case you should have following line in your `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.node/bin:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin
```

And remove all unnecessary aliases.

Comment: thanks for your answer! Can you explain why the use of aliases is bad practive? Also since i use that path in my bash_profile, what should be the path inside my main .bashrc file? Just an empy file? or the basic path like this: export PATH=$PATH:$HOME ?

Comment: if i echo $path after these changes i get the following : `/Users/christoph/.node/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`, the changes are not visible it seems.

Comment: You need to login again (or you can invoke `source .bash_profile`) for it to update. Aliases are not bad practice, but they are designed for something different: modifying behaviour of existing commands - e.g.: I have defined following aliases: `alias ll='ls -l'` `alias ssh='ssh -X'`, `alias ocaml='rlwrap ocaml'`, etc.

Comment: ok, that makes sense . My bash_profile has the longer path and is working now, and my .bashrc file has this path : export PATH="$PATH" .  is this correct or should i change the main file to something different?

Comment: It's OK - you can remove this line from bashrc completely :)